# Rails, Devise. Disallow User actions unless AdminUser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have **User** model created with Devise, with **type:string** attribute and a **AdminUser** model (`AdminUser < User`).

In application controller I defined the **:require_admin** method:

```
  def require_admin
    unless current_user == AdminUser
      flash[:error] = "You are not an admin"
      redirect_to store_index_path
    end
  end
```

On products controller I set

```
before_action :require_admin, except: :show
```

Now I create an AdminUser via console successfully (with AdminUser id) and when I log in the app, I still can not use those actions (create, edit etc.).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
current_user == AdminUser
```

you check whether `current_user` object *is equal* to the `AdminUser` class.

What you want instead is to check whether `current_user`'s class is `AdminUser`:

```
current_user.class == AdminUser
# or
current_user.is_a?(AdminUser)
# or
current_user.kind_of?(AdminUser)
# or
current_user.instance_of?(AdminUser)
# or
AdminUser === current_user
```

Comment: Perfect! Case is closed

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be `current_user.is_a?(AdminUser)`

Source : [is_a? method documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/is_a%3F)