# Check if user is logged in, else redirect to login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm newbie in Ruby on Rails and currently i'm developing my first app, Devise apparently is the best gem to get this action (authentication). But i'm not understand how to work.

To create a simple blog is very easy the Getting Starter Guide, i've great ideas to use RoR, but depends how to work it with Devise.

I try this url:

[Rails 3 + Devise: user_signed_in? for a different user in the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272813/rails-3-devise-user-signed-in-for-a-different-user-in-the-database) (from 2010) not work

[Rails, Devise. Disallow User actions unless AdminUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523437/rails-devise-disallow-user-actions-unless-adminuser?rq=1) (Is'nt my issue)

If you have other way to use authentication for newbies developers in this language, please tell me

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# Devise for login
gem 'devise'

# Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'

# Google Web Fonts
gem 'google-webfonts-rails'
```

In advance, thank you

Comment: Don't take it for granted that you have to use devise. There are many tutorials for writing your own Auth in Rails and it will teach you how things work under the hood.

Comment: Okay, but others developers tell me "This gem solve your request: Devise, learn how to use it" :/

Comment: In my experience  devise is easy at first but is not  really beginner friendly when it comes time to customize it. In the long term its good to understand how auth really works, because its actually not that complicated

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the built in Devise method authenticate_user! (or whatever your model name is)? Usually this is implemented at a controller level in a before_action statement, like this:

```
class Controller < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

You can also limit the actions where the before action is applied. That method will do exactly what you want, will first check if the user is logged in and redirect to the sign up page otherwise.

Comment: My model name is 'user' (by default), i write your suggest on dashboard_controller.rb (Because is my index page where i need to check user logged in) console return: 'undefined method `authenticate_user!' for #<DashboardController:0x007f32f9fc68f8> Did you mean? authenticate_with_http_digest'

Comment: Have you properly configured Devise following the documentation? You need to add some methods in the User model and the routes file

Answer (score 0):

`before_action :authenticate_user!` // Add this to your controller

Assuming that your model is user. If your model is name other than user(For ex: member) user `authenticate_member!`